# How to fix broken controllers/pads?

Tags: controllers

Recently, I took off my old consoles from their boxes with the intention to do some retro-gaming but found two problems which look alike: my gamecube controller has a problem where it's digital stick seems fixed to a direction (try to play metroid prime with that if you can) and my playstation2 dualshock seems to have broken something since triangle, x and circle doesn't work.

I fixed previously my old supernintendo controllers but since those two look a little more complex so I want some information before breaking them without return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PS2 controller is fairly simple to take apart. Sounds like the contacts are probably dirty and just not making contact properly for the buttons.

Link+Video: http://screwattack.com/videos/How-to-take-apart-and-clean-your-PS2-controller

Not sure about the gamecube controller.

Comment: Will try tomorrow, but by looking the video seems easy, thumbs up

Comment: The link is dead now. Is this video on youtube or somewhere else?  http://web.archive.org/web/20101110085506/http://screwattack.com/videos/How-to-take-apart-and-clean-your-PS2-controller is just spinning so far but maybe will eventually load.